# Append/Add string to folder/directory name

Tags: c#

So I have a `path` that looks like this:

```
MyFiles/Folder1
MyFiles/Folder2
```

I want to use `Directory.Move` to dynamically add a string (`My_`) to their filename like this:

```
MyFiles/My_Folder1
MyFiles/My_Folder2
```

I tried something like this (for each loop):

```
path_SS = diag.SelectedPath;
Directory.Move(path_SS, $"My_{path_SS}");
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

The folder completely disappeared

Comment: `"It doesn't seem to work"` isn't a terribly useful description of the problem you're having. Can you explain in more detail? Are the files moved to the wrong place? Do you get an exception? If so, what does that exception contain?

Comment: Your folder probably didn't disappear, it was moved to `"My_MyFiles/Folder1"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course what you have wouldn't work. You're adding that substring to the beginning of the entire path, not the last node in the path. If you want to change that last node, you have remove it from the path, change it and then add the result back. You can use the `System.IO.Path` class to manipulate file and folder paths:

```cs
var sourceFolderPath = diag.SelectedPath;
var parentFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFolderPath);
var sourceFolderName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFolderPath);
var targetFolderName = $"My_{sourceFolderName}";
var targetFolderPath = Path.Combine(parentFolderPath, targetFolderName);

Directory.Move(sourceFolderPath, targetFolderPath);
```

Note that `Path.GetFileName` just gets the last node in a path, whether it represents a file or folder.

Note also the descriptive variable names, where "path_SS" is bad name.